# Triggering a click for a control in a update panel problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using a RadListView and i want to click a checkbox/button (It displays as a checkbox but its designer code shows it as a button). But every time i call the click method the page refreshes instead of updating the update panel which contains the list view.

How do i call the click event without the page posting back instead of the update panel?

```
  <asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select"
                                            CssClass="rlvBSel" Text=" " ToolTip="Select" />
```

Code:

```
                 $(".rlvI, .rlvA").click(function () {
                 $(this).find(".rlvBSel").click();
             });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your page does a full postback instead of an asynchronous.

Is the Button inside of the UpdatePanel or outside? If the latter(or it's [ChildrenAsTriggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx) is set to `false`) you must define an [AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) in the UpdatePanel.

For example:

```
<Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SelectButton" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Maybe it'll solve your issue if you set `clientIDMode="AutoID"`

```
<pages clientIDMode="AutoID"></pages>
```

http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2011/05/linkbutton-inside-listview-cause-full.html

Comment: Thats exactly it, the button is inside of the update panel but it posts back the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to refresh the UpdatePanel I believe you can do this:

```
$(".rlvI, .rlvA").click(function () {
             __doPostBack('myUpdatePanel', '');
         });
```